# Java: apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate with a timezone

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-8, timezone

### Background & Purpose

- I want to parse `String` into `Date` using `apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate`, but have a problem, which may be related to timezones.
- I'm currently in China (Timezone: CST = GMT+8).

### Code

- I created a variable `date`, which is `Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2024`.
- I expect the second variable `date2` to be the same as `date`, `Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2024`, but the actual value is `Wed Jan 10 14:00:00 CST 2024`.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ClassTest {

    private static final String[] parsePatterns = {"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"};

    public void methodTest() throws Exception {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2024, Calendar.JANUARY, 10, 0, 0, 0);

        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(date); // Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2024

        Date date2 = org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(date.toString(), parsePatterns);
        System.out.println(date2); // Wed Jan 10 14:00:00 CST 2024
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassTest ct = new ClassTest();
        try {
            ct. methodTest();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

### Versions

Java: 8
Apache commons lang: 3.9

Comment: Is it possible for you to use java.time instead of Calendar and Date?  There's a reason those classes shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: Using `java.time` is a last resort for us because our legacy code has lots of `Calendar` and `Date`.

Comment: @dmjy Much safer to write new code all in *java.time*. Where you have to interact with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert back and forth between legacy and modern classes by calling new conversion methods added to the old classes.

Comment: You can’t do that. CST is ambiguous, so while China Standard Time is abbreviated CST in the return value from `date.toString()`, CST may be interpreted as Australian Central Standard Time, North American Central Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time when parsing. Whlie java.time allows you to control the interpretation, I doubt that the Apache `DateUtils.parseDate()` does.

Comment: Related and similar: [IST mapped to wrong ZoneId in java.time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733849/ist-mapped-to-wrong-zoneid-in-java-time-library)

Comment: Also see [my answer to another related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374732/5772882).

Comment: *Using `java.time` is a last resort for us because our legacy code has lots of `Calendar` and `Date`.* Poor you. Don’t let it stop you from starting using java.time immediately, though. [See the solution using java.time run online.](https://rextester.com/IYIG44690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you are better off using the java.time and java.time.format packages.

If you cannot move away from Date, Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat, you will need to tell the SimpleDateFormat what “CST” means.

Like most three-letter abbreviations for timezones, “CST” has multiple meanings.  To someone in China, it means Beijing Time, but to the US, it means Central Standard Time.  Java is mostly written in the US (I’m pretty sure), so it tends to favor the American meaning of CST.

You can tell a SimpleDateFormat exactly what you want CST to signify, by creating a [DateFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) which explicitly defines the timezones it recognizes.  Here is a DateFormatSymbols which only recognizes the Asia/Shanghai timezone, and that timezone’s short name, "CST":

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);

TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai");
symbols.setZoneStrings(new String[][] {
    {
        zone.getID(),
        zone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG),
        zone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT), // "CST"
        zone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.LONG),
        zone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT),
    }
});
```

Now we can use that DateFormatSymbols with a SimpleDateFormat:

```
String pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, symbols);

Date date = format.parse("Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2024");
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: While well explained and correct the details of this answer were outdated some 10 years before the answer was written. The OP and everyone else are much, much better off using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.  See [IST mapped to wrong ZoneId in java.time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733849/ist-mapped-to-wrong-zoneid-in-java-time-library).

Comment: @Anonymous That was literally the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Yes it was. So why are you using the rest of the answer contradicting it? The OP informed us that they are using Java 8, so they *can* move away from the old classes and their severe design problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the format you created when printing or stringifying but you need to use proper date classes and there's no need for 3rd party:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Jan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String DATE_PAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        final String ZONE_PAT = "Asia/Shanghai";
        ZonedDateTime janTen = ZonedDateTime.of(2024, Month.JANUARY.getValue(), 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of(ZONE_PAT));
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PAT, Locale.US);
        System.out.println(janTen.format(dtf));
        String display = dtf.format(janTen);
        ZonedDateTime x = ZonedDateTime.parse(display, dtf);
        System.out.println(x.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

Comment: It only appears to give the correct result. At least on my computer it parses into `2024-01-10T00:00-06:00[America/Chicago]`, which is incorrect. The error is hidden when formatting back but will manifest if you try to use `x` for other purposes. Using java.time is the obvious good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Just set `Locale` to `DateUtils`:

```java
private static final String parsePattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
//...
Date date2 = DateUtils.parseDate(date.toString(), Locale.ENGLISH, DF_PATTERN);
//...
```

Comment: It does not work, sorry. I got `Wed Jan 10 14:00:00 CST 2024`, wrong by 14 hours, exactly as in the question. I also see no reason why it might have helped. And using the `Date` class is still discouraged. (I assumed that `DF_PATTERN` was supposed to refer to your `parsePattern`.)